# How to connect to an Azure Storage account from a service running on service fabric cluster?

Tags: azure

All the resources are in the same resource group. I have a service deployed in the service fabric cluster and I have a storage account. I also have registered an app in Azure Active Directory. How do I connect to the storage account? I want to use certificate/token based authentication and not connection strings.

I am pretty new to azure so I am confused about the basic stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Managed Identities and grant access to it in your storage account.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/concepts-managed-identity

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-managed-identity